# Response model for specific status codes using Swagger

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, swagger

I am using [Swagger](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle) to document my REST API (using asp.net web api 2). Is there a way in swagger to give response models for each possible responses for a given api call? I am annotating the status code response using the xml comments like so:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Save a person
    /// </summary>
    /// <response code="200">Ok</response>
    /// <response code="400">Bad Request</response>
    /// <response code="500">Internal Server error</response>
    public HttpResponseMessage SavePerson() {...}
```

[image]

Comment: You may want to follow this - https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/254.

Comment: In .NET Core .31/Swashbuckle 5, `<response code="...">...</response>` works as expected: see #3 at https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#user-content-include-descriptions-from-xml-comments for an example.

Comment: I just simply solved the status code 200 to 400 while changing the return type from return Ok(json_structure); to  return new JsonResult(json_structure); in the exception handler, and the issue is well solved ! .

Answer (score 52):

You can try using cref="TYPE HERE" on your XML comments like this.

```
/// <response code="400" cref="CustomErrorModel">Bad Request</response>
```

B
ut I would suggest using annotations that Swagger gives you.

```
[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Type = typeof(OnlineMerchantQueryResponseInformation))]
```

attribute your Controllers with this.

Comment: it would be good if you can share from where you found this documentation?

Comment: does the first approach here (xml comment) really work for anyone? `Cref` has some IntelliSense, but in my attempts the model does not appear in generated swagger document (despite using  `swaggerGenOptions.IncludeXmlComments(xmlDocFile);`). The approach with the attribute works, however.

Comment: SwaggerResponse will not work if you doesn't tell to.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51974264/swashbuckle-aspnetcore-swaggeroperation-attribute-not-found

Comment: @PawełBulwan The XML approach didn't work for me.  The attribute-based approach (i.e. `[SwaggerResponse()]`) worked for me the first time I tried it, so that's what I'm going with.

Answer (score 34):

Your signature says you're returning a HttpResponseMessage, not a data model.  If you're returning an IActionResult, and you're using ASP.NET Core, you can use the "ProducesResponseType" attribute:

```cs
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<YourModel>), 200)]
```

ProducesResponsesType is in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc namespace.

See
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#list-operation-responses
"Explicit Responses"

Comment: That's only valid in Core.

Answer (score 19):

If you are using Swashbuckle, You can try

```
 [SwaggerResponse(200, typeof(CustomModel))]
```

and you additionally add a comment for that response type as an optional third parameter

```
[SwaggerResponse(200, typeof(CustomModel), "returns a new id of the bla bla")]
```

Note: The attribute is in namespace **Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations**

Comment: This requires NSwag.Annotations.

Comment: For .NET framework (not .NET Core) the Swashbuckle namespace to use is: using Swashbuckle.Swagger.Annotations

Comment: For .NET Framework, in addition to the namespace change mentioned by @robnick, I found the attribute has the type and description switched: `[SwaggerResponse(200, "blah blah", typeof(CustomModel))]`.