# Swashbuckle.AspNetCore SwaggerOperation attribute not found

Tags: asp.net-core, swashbuckle

I am trying to use Autorest and Swagger documentation created by the help of Swashbuckle.AspNetCore (3.0.0) in order to generate a REST API client.

The swagger documentation generated seems to be correct except that the operation name are not really nice.

```js
"/api/Addresses/{id}": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [ "Address" ],
        "operationId": "ApiAddressesByIdGet",
        "consumes": [],
        "produces": [],
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "id",
            "in": "path",
            "required": true,
            "type": "string",
            "format": "uuid"
          }
        ],
        "responses": { "200": { "description": "Success" } }
      },
```

I saw in many articles and also on the official documentation of SwashBuckle.AspNetCore that I can use an attribute to decorate my controller method like this:

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Produces("application/json")]
[ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(List<AddressDto>), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
[SwaggerOperation("GetAllAdresses")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllAsync()
{
   ....
}
```

Unfortunately, I got an error:

> SwaggerOperationAttribute could not be found

I verified the NuGet packages installed and they are:

- SwashBuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger (3.0.0)
- SwashBuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen (3.0.0)
- SwashBuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI (3.0.0)

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I ran across this today.  I needed to add the following nuget package that was just added for V3.0.0:

[Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations/)

Breaking changes are described [here](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/releases/tag/v3.0.0)

Please also note that you need to add the following to Startup.cs or your Swagger extension:

```
AddSwaggerGen(c => { ... c.EnableAnnotations(); })
```

Comment: Thanks that helped me out. Also good to comment, at first it did not work for me I had to enable Annotations in Startup.cs

services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
   ...

   c.EnableAnnotations();
});

More info: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#swashbuckleaspnetcoreannotations

Comment: Thank you so very much! I needed to override the operationid and I was able to do so!

See [Github](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#swashbuckleaspnetcoreannotations) for everything you can do with annotations!

Comment: @ScottG are you able to help with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72853488/display-different-controller-name-in-swagger

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to set `Name` property for your `HttpGet` filter like this:

```cs
[HttpGet(Name = "GetAllAdresses")]
[Produces("application/json")]
[ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(List<AddressDto>), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
[SwaggerOperation("GetAllAdresses")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllAsync()
{
   ....
}
```